# Run protractor tests with different window sizes?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, protractor

I want to start 4 different chrome windows to run the same tests on 4 resolutions. –

I know protractor has a feature called multiCapabilities, and I know you can set the window size like this: 
`browser.manage().window().setSize(320, 480);`

But I don't really find a way to combine these 2. Or is there an easier way to create this behaviour

Comment: Do you mean that you want to set a different window size depending on the testing browser running?

Comment: No, I want to start 4 different chrome windows to run the same tests on 4 resolutions. (I edited my question)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A very simple solution that comes in my mind would be to create a `for` loop in your test file with a `switch` to make your tests running 4 times with a different resolution.

At the beginning of your specs:

```
describe('myApp', function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        switch (i) {
            case 0:
                //set resolution 1
                browser.manage().window().setSize(320, 480);
                break;
            case 1:
                //set resolution 2
                browser.manage().window().setSize(600, 800);
                break;
            case 2:
                //set resolution 3
                browser.manage().window().setSize(768, 1024);
                break;
            case 3:
                //set resolution 4
                browser.manage().window().setSize(1080, 1920);
                break;
            default:
                return;
        }
    }
    // beforeEach() {...};
    // it('should do something', function(){...};
});
```

Answer (score 27):

As for me, the best way is to add `multiCapabilities` in config:

```
multiCapabilities: [{
   'browserName': 'chrome',
   'chromeOptions' : {
       args: ['--lang=en',
              '--window-size=800,800']
   },

   specs: ['spec.js']
},{
   'browserName': 'chrome',
   'chromeOptions' : {
    args: ['--lang=en',
           '--window-size=350,650']
   },

   specs: ['spec.js']
   // and so on
}]
```

Comment: Add some details and explain :)

Comment: Its quite more comfortable, because you can define different specs for  each browser configuration in conf and keep your tests untouchable.
For example - i have 5 tests, 3 of them are only for iPad resolution, its much easier to edit conf file once, than edit every spec...

Comment: This was helpful to me, although I had to do some digging. You might check out the following additional resources: https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/spec/shardingConf.js
https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/browser-setup.md
https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/DesiredCapabilities https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities

Comment: this would run the tests in parallel , correct?  If I want them done serially then I need to use @glepretre 's solution

Comment: I choose this option because it works for incognito mode, while `.setSize()` method is only available in normal mode.