# Run protractor test in chrome with different resolutions

Tags: javascript, protractor

I am trying to make my spec run on 4 different resolutions.
I tried to add multiple capabilities as was suggested here [Run protractor tests with different window sizes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22305297/run-protractor-tests-with-different-window-sizes).
First:

```
multiCapabilities: [{
   'browserName': 'chrome',
   'chromeOptions' : {
       args: ['--lang=en',
              '--window-size=1200,800']
   }
},{
   'browserName': 'chrome',
   'chromeOptions' : {
    args: ['--lang=en',
           '--window-size=768,650']
   }
   // and so on
}]
```

As well the browser size opens in proper way (with pointed window size), but then is set to default.

I tried to add foor loop after describe, but it also does not work, or any loop should be inside 'it'.
This code was used:

```
describe('myApp', function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        switch (i) {
            case 0:
                //set resolution 1
                browser.manage().window().setSize(320, 480);
                break;
            case 1:
                //set resolution 2
                browser.manage().window().setSize(600, 800);
                break;
            case 2:
                //set resolution 3
                browser.manage().window().setSize(768, 1024);
                break;
            case 3:
                //set resolution 4
                browser.manage().window().setSize(1080, 1920);
                break;
            default:
                return;
        }
    }
    // Open tranformify
    beforeAll(function() {
        browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
        browser.get(browser.baseUrl);
        homePage.partner_btn_fn(0);
        loginPage.log_in(helper.part_email, helper.pswd);

    });


    it('Post a project with all empty fields', function() {}
});
```

Thanks for the answers.

Comment: can you show what you have tried so far?

Comment: Sure. I have tried this: multiCapabilities: [{
   'browserName': 'chrome',
   'chromeOptions' : {
       args: ['--lang=en',
              '--window-size=800,800']
   },

   specs: ['spec.js']
},{
   'browserName': 'chrome',
   'chromeOptions' : {
    args: ['--lang=en',
           '--window-size=350,650']
   },

   specs: ['spec.js']
   // and so on
}] and also tried this loop after describe section for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        switch (i) {
            case 0:
                browser.manage().window().setSize(320, 480);
                break