# Determining browser capabilities during test runs

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I have a need to test against different screen sizes in my protractor test suites, and after a quick search came across this post [Run protractor tests with different window sizes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22305297/run-protractor-tests-with-different-window-sizes)

One of the answers talks about using the multipleCapabilities config option which looks to be a nice and concise approach.

I was wondering if there is a way to name these capabilities with some sort of alias or similar which could be interrogated during the tests, so to check what 'mode' the test is running in, e.g, small screen, large screen, etc.

Currently I have separate test files named like feature.sm.spec.js, feature.lg.spec.js, which set the screen size in a beforeAll(), one of the tests checks table responsiveness so checks the right number of columns and the column headings text are what they should be.

It would be nice if I could have just the one test spec file, and using the current screen size mode its running under, the expectation could be varied dynamically, e.g. in some utility functions, so I just check the expected columns based on the known screen size.

Anyone out there done this kinda thing?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things that come to mind are you could create a different test suite to run for each screen size, or pass in the screen size you want to test using a command line argument, which can be defined in your `conf.js` You would use the `params` object and can access that value in your specs using `browser.params.YourObjectOrVarHere`.

If you want just one spec file, i think the `browser.params` approach would work best for you, but you would have to run the test for each screen size.

Comment: Thanks this looks like just what I need!

Answer (score 1):

The simple approach for the problem is by passing the screen size as command line arguments and in `onPrepare()` method you can set the browser size based on the parameter passed. Look at below example spec.

```
exports.config = {
    capabilities: {
        browserName: 'chrome',
    },
    onPrepare: function () {
        if(browser.params.screenSize){
            var width = browser.params.screenSize.split("x")[0]
            var height = browser.params.screenSize.split("x")[1]
            browser.manage().window().setSize(parseInt(width), parseInt(height));
        }else{
           browser.manage().window().maximize();
        }
    },
    params : {
      screenSize : "1420x850" //default screensize
    }
}
```

And in terminal use the below command to pass the screenSize as parameter.

```
protractor config.js --params.screenSize 1920x900
```

Now the browser will be launched and set's the screen size as `1920x900`

Comment: Thanks it's a shame I can't accept multiple answers, but this builds on Vinnys one quite nicely

Comment: No probs!! Glad you accepted Vinny`s answer. I just wanted to give a small example on how to proceed with Vinny's suggestion!!